# Leaner Code to reduce multiple replace() functions

Tags: r, vector, replace, rounding

To optimize my code I am looking for a way to combine many successive `replace()` functions. I have a list of numbers between 1 and 2500. Each number should be rounded up to the next higher hundred (5 -> 100, 136 -> 200, etc.) category. Is there a more elegant solution for this?

At the moment it looks like this:

```
ls <- c(1,126,1399,857,94,543)

ls <- replace(ls, ls > 1 & ls < 100, 100)
ls <- replace(ls, ls > 100.1 & ls < 200, 200)
ls <- replace(ls, ls > 200.1 & ls < 300, 300)
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ceiling` to round up to the nearest higher integer:

```r
ceiling(ls / 100) * 100
#[1]  100  200 1400  900  100  600
```